QGIS Join attributes by field value tool is missing a lot of valid matches depending on order of inputs - is there another way?
I have two layers:

A vector point layer of all of the postcode centroid locations in the UK (OS CodePoint Open)

A non-geospatial table layer containing a column called 'Postcode', plus various other columns


I want to join these two together, so that I have a vector point layer containing all the information in the non-geospatial layer plus the point geometries.
I am using the 'Join attributes by field value' processing tool. My initial attempt was to use the tool with the non-geospatial layer as Input Layer 1 and the point layer as Input Layer 2, but when I do the join the geometry doesn't get 'copied across' - so the result is still a non-geospatial layer. Is there any way to do this join and bring across the geometry? When running this I find that 90% of my postcodes in the non-geospatial layer match a postcode in the vector layer (OS CodePoint Open) - this makes sense, as a few postcodes are invalid or missing but most are ok.
When I reverse the order of the layers - that is, have the point layer as Input Layer 1 and the non-geospatial layer as Input Layer 2 and tick 'discard records which could not be joined', I get a point layer as output - but it only manages to match around 50% of the postcodes in the non-geospatial layer. Why is it matching fewer records in this case? I'd have expected the results to be the same - if they match one way around then why wouldn't they match the other way around?
It's very difficult to tell which records it thinks don't match, as if I don't tick 'discard records which could not be joined' then I get back a record for each of the millions of records in OS CodePoint Open, and most of them are genuine non-matches.
Unfortunately I can't share the non-geospatial table that we're using, but the point layer is the OS CodePoint Open.

Do you have any duplicate Postcode in your non spatial layer ? if yes this explain why you dont get the same number of matches depending on order…

Oh of course, that makes total sense. Thank you very much. I'll update this with an answer explaining that in more detail later.
